# Homebrew: Cask 'java' definition is invalid

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I started getting the following error when updating my casks recently:

```
Error: Cask 'java' definition is invalid: Token '{:v1=>"java"}' in header line does not match the file name.
```

I'm on MacOS 10.14.4, and my Homebrew version:

```
→ brew --version
Homebrew 2.1.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 6811d1; last commit 2019-05-11)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision ba4e3; last commit 2019-05-11)
```

Here's the output of `brew cask upgrade --verbose --debug`:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
angular-cli          atlassian-cli        libpqxx              terraforming
app-engine-python    elasticsearch        osm2pgrouting
asciidoctorj         jenkins-lts          postgresql

==> Casks with `auto_updates` or `version :latest` will not be upgraded
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
Error: Cask 'java' definition is invalid: Token '{:v1=>"java"}' in header line does not match the file name.
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cask_loader.rb:73:in `cask'
/usr/local/Caskroom/java/.metadata/1.8.0_51-b16/20150725210402.758/Casks/java.rb:1:in `load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cask_loader.rb:62:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cask_loader.rb:62:in `load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cask_loader.rb:178:in `load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd/upgrade.rb:39:in `block in run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd/upgrade.rb:37:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd/upgrade.rb:37:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd/abstract_command.rb:36:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:92:in `run_command'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:158:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:123:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/cask.rb:9:in `cask'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:102:in `<main>'
Error: Kernel.exit
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:162:in `exit'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:162:in `rescue in run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:146:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:123:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/cask.rb:9:in `cask'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:102:in `<main>'
```

and the output of `brew tap`:

```
beeftornado/rmtree
heroku/brew
homebrew/cask
homebrew/core
homebrew/services
```

Here's the output of `brew doctor` if it helps:

```
→ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/icu-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/krb5-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/freetype-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/xslt-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/libpng16-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/python3.6m-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/libpng-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/xml2-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/python3-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/curl-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/ncursesw6-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/pcre-config
  /Users/myUser/anaconda3/bin/python3.6-config
  /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/gdal-config

Warning: Some installed formulae are not readable:
  dotwrp: Unsupported special dependency :fortran
(base)
```

I've searched but cannot seem to find a way to fix this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does running `brew update` fix the problem?

Comment: Unfortunatley not :(

Comment: I ran `brew update; brew upgrade; brew cask upgrade; brew cleanup;`

Comment: Might be similar to this issue? -- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/53079

Comment: That thread says to uninstall and reinstall Homebrew. That might be problematic as I'd remove ALL installed packages along with Homebrew. It's a pretty dramatic way to solve the error I'm receiving no?

Comment: I was hoping you would update your question with the output of the commands so that would help us nail the problem more easily.

Comment: @AshwanthKumar done

Comment: What about `brew doctor`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni added the output of that command as well now. Thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Solved by doing the following:

1. Edited the java cask:

```
vim /usr/local/Caskroom/java/.metadata/1.8.0_51-b16/20150725210402.758/Casks/java.rb
```

2. Changed the first line from:

`cask :v1 => 'java' do`

to

`cask 'java' do`

3. Removed the `undent` comments at the end of the cask, which were giving me problems.
4. Ran `brew uninstall --cask java`

Problem solved

Comment: If I could upvote this answer fifty times, I would!  I have been fighting with a broken java installation, literally, for years.  I did one more step, which was to do a "brew cask uninstall --force java".

Comment: Any idea what causes this problem to begin with?

Comment: Step 3 was the step that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This was really helpful. What does everyone do *after* uninstalling java? Do you install via homebrew again, or go through the native OSX install? According to my notes, I installed Java via brew cask after upgrading to Yosemite, 5 years ago. But I don't recall why I installed it.

Comment: Thank you! For future searchers: I also had to comment out a line reading `license :gratis` to get it to work. I did _not_ have to change the `undent` comment at the end of the cask.

Comment: applied the same instructions to remove an old version of flash and it worked! thanks!

Comment: I also had to delete two blocks containing `if MacOS.release <= :mavericks` due to `Error: Cask 'java' is unreadable: undefined method `release' for OS::Mac:Module`

Comment: Step 4 is now: `brew uninstall --cask java`

Comment: I used this solution for a similar error but for virtualbox:
Error: Cask 'virtualbox' definition is invalid: Token '{:v1=>"virtualbox"}' in header line does not match the file name.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 8):

You can clean up old-style cask formulas thus:

```
grep "cask :v1 =>" --files-with-match /usr/local/Caskroom/*/.metadata/*/*/Casks/*.rb \
  | xargs gdirname | xargs gdirname | xargs rm -r
```

Assuming you've installed [coreutils](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) with a `g` prefix, so `gdirname` runs the GNU flavor of `dirname`

Comment: Thanks, this saved me from `Cask 'virtualbox' definition is invalid: Token '{:v1=>"virtualbox"}' in header line does not match the file name.`