# on mac brew, i cannot uninstall software

Tags: macos, homebrew

environment:

- Big Sur
- brew -v

  - Hovmebrew 3.2.0
  - Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 0d0ad73336; last commit 2021-07-04)
  - Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 7f9debbd51; last commit 2021-07-04)

uninstall application(filezilla) & error message

```
vikke@shincho:~
$ brew uninstall filezilla
Error: Cask 'filezilla' definition is invalid: Token '{:v1=>"filezilla"}' in header line does not match the file name.
```

How to do it?

Comment: This answer did the trick for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64405089/4997329

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor`?